# move_uploaded_file permission denied

Tags: php

I'm getting error in uploading image to directory folder named `images`. Though I created a folder `images`.

Error Occur

```
1. Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/Rachel Leigh Cook.jpg): failed to open stream: 
2. Permission denied in /usr/home/mer/public_html/salico/ZNote/php/image_upload_do.php 
3. Unable to move '/var/tmp/phpGV5fVF' to 'imagesRachel Leigh Cook.jpg' in 
   /usr/home/mer/public_html/salico/ZNote/php/image_upload_do.php
```

My code

```
$upfile = ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) ) ? $_FILES['userfile'] : '' ;

if ( is_array( $upfile ) ) {

    $file_name = $upfile['name'];
    $file_temp = $upfile['tmp_name'];

    $dir_file = 'images/'.$file_name;

    if ( is_uploaded_file( $file_temp ) ) {

        if ( move_uploaded_file( $file_temp, $dir_file ) ) {
            echo 'Successfully Uploaded';
        } else {
            echo 'Failed to upload';
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is nothing wrong in my code. Do I need to edit the `php.ini` file?

Comment: rights issue .Give permission to upload directory

Comment: thanks @mahmoodRehman. but where can I set or give permission to upload directory?

Comment: Your operating system ? linux or windows ?

Comment: windows. but I'm using vmware player to run freebsd(linux) to run apache

Comment: what's the current permission of the directory ?

Comment: can rename, remove, add file sir! Error also listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run chmod for images folder like this :

```
chmod -R 777 images
```

And also on php folder    `chmod -R 777 php`

Comment: Thanks. Work great bro! :))

Comment: Welcome dear.Happy programming.

Comment: Anyways, is there any alternative way in uploading image to directory, by not using chmod?

Comment: chmod is command for permissions.you will always need this if you have to work with permissions.For more visit this link[http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php]

Comment: ok bro! thanks. last question! haha :D. what if I run this using wamp or xampp(windows), do I get same error?

Comment: May be not but if got then you can set folder permission by properties.

Answer (score 1):

run `chmod` command to path folder.

Comment: Thanks but nothing. when I run this code "  chmod -R 755 images "

Comment: usually i use chmod 777

Answer (score 0):

Go to respective folder .. in this case `images` and run.

```
chmod -R 777
```